# Can't see entry in multiple site mode (EE5)

Tags: ee5, multiple-sites

I have an English language version of the main site installed in multiple site mode (there is no problem with it inside admin panel: I can switch sites, create channels/entries, manage templates for both sites etc.) — [en.kiosov.pro](https://en.kiosov.pro). The index page is working well. But I can't see channel page and entries page at all. For example, I have a channel called ***Cases*** with one entry inside. I have a template group called ***cases*** too with 2 templates inside:

***index***

```
{embed="index/header" my_html_class="cases" my_page_title="Cases"}
{exp:channel:entries channel='cases' limit='25' my_active_nav='cases' paginate='bottom' dynamic='no'}
    <div class="blog-entry">
        <h2><a href="{url_title_path='cases/case'}">{title}</a></h2>
        <p>{entry_date format='%n/%j/%Y'}</p>
        <p>{case_teaser}</p>
        {if has_categories}
            <p><b>in</b>: {categories backspace='2'}<a href="{path=/'cases/'}" title="View more in {category_name}">{category_name}</a>, {/categories}</p>
        {/if}
        <p>by: {author}</p>
    </div>
    {if no_results}
        {redirect='404'}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{embed="index/footer"}
```

and ***case***

```
{embed="index/header" my_html_class="cases" my_page_title="Cases"}
{exp:channel:entries channel='cases' limit='1' require_entry='yes'}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <p>{entry_date format='%n/%j/%Y'}</p>
    <p>{case_teaser}</p>
    <p>{case_post}</p>
    {if has_categories}
        <p><b>in</b>: {categories backspace='2'}<a href="{path='cases'}" title="View more in {category_name}">{category_name}</a>, {/categories}</p>
    {/if}
    <p>by: {author}</p>
    {if no_results}
        {redirect='404'}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{embed="index/footer"}
```

I have the entries listing code on index page which is works well (you can see it on [en.kiosov.pro/#cases](https://en.kiosov.pro/#cases) page)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="cases" limit="5" my_active_nav="cases" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}
<h3><a href="{url_title_path='cases/case'}">{title}</a></h3>
<h4>{case_teaser}</h4>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It builds the correct link to the entry but I get “Not Found” when I click it or just type the [link](https://en.kiosov.pro/cases/case/first-test-case-post) (for example) in the browser URL field. Can’t realize what I missed for en. version because the main site ([kiosov.pro](https://kiosov.pro)  — just old design and structure there) works without that problem and I building en. version with the same way (but other channels structure).

Thank you!

Comment: What is purpose of the parameter `my_active_nav` included in your channel:entries tags?  It is not a standard parameter for EE.

Comment: @jcogs.eecms Don't remember, it's from old design templates which are works since ee2. I just clean the code and remove `my_html_class`, `my_page_title` and `my_active_nav` parameters but it didn't help with my issue.

Comment: Again probably nothing - but it appears you have unnecessary `/` characters in the line generating links in your index code `href="{path=/'cases/'}"`.  The sample link you included (https://en.kiosov.pro/cases/case/first-test-case-post) seems to work without problem too.  Perhaps if you can make clearer what the issue is (e.g. with working example) it might be easier to work out what issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

You must copy `.htaccess` file for the second site which works in multiple site mode not just `index.php` and `admin.php` as the documentation says.